# Are these tasks all doable in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm not all that familiar with sharepoint.  A client of ours asked if the following can be setup in sharepoint. I believe the following is all achievable, however he had a few questions, which I've included at the bottom.  Here's the description:

Client wants to catalog all of his images in sharepoint. These images are used for marketing, annual reports, etc.  Here are some features they need:

- We’ll setup a subsite and make this guy an admin. He can edit a couple of group memberships to define who can have full access and who has read only.
- Let him upload pictures…this is a photo library. Probably in a document library. He’ll need metatags, or custom fields. Description, expiration date, some others.
- Give them some views grouping by some of this metadata. Like country.
- Send out a weekly report of images nearing expiration.
- When images have expired, delete them automatically
- General search that will search all metatags and return hits

---

And here are his questions:

Couple of questions (not sure if these are possible):
-          They would like to have a low quality image with a watermark over top of it for read only people. And they would have to click to ask for permission for the full version. The manager would get an email when this permission is asked for. Not sure what is the easiest way after that. Maybe the manager clicks something that will email the full image to that person. If this is doable, write up for me how it would work. So people with full permission see the full image, people with read only see the watermark version.

- Is it possible to have it search by only one field, like country. Or give them to the choice to do a general search for all.
- In sharepoint, is it possible to show a thumbprint image in the list of pictures? So if they search and get 10 results, they see the thumbnail and they don’t have to click on each one to even see a basic picture.

Are these all doable in sharepoint?

Thanks

Comment: Questions like this should go to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ unless you are asking how to create one of those features in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let him upload pictures…this is a photo library. Probably in a
>   document library. He’ll need metatags, or custom fields. Description,
>   expiration date, some others.
>
> Give them some views grouping by some of this metadata. Like country.
>
> Send out a weekly report of images nearing expiration.
>
> When images have expired, delete them automatically
>
> General search that will search all metatags and return hits

Everything in the first section SharePoint provides out of the box. The email may be the hardest part but even then it is likely a simple timer job.

> a low quality image with a watermark over top of it for read only
>   people

Showing different images based on user security may be tricky. There is the ability for each item in a library to have its own security but it can be hard to maintain and slow down performance so I would recommend storing them in two lists. One for the watermark images and one for the full image. Linking the two is easy.

> Is it possible to have it search by only one field, like country. Or
>   give them to the choice to do a general search for all.

Searching on one field and general search is also provided out of the box and you can create custom pages with any kind of search you could need.

> In sharepoint, is it possible to show a thumbprint image in the list
>   of pictures? So if they search and get 10 results, they see the
>   thumbnail and they don’t have to click on each one to even see a basic
>   picture.

I know the 2013 search provides a preview but I do not know about 2010.